# I want to use the woocommerce hook in wordpress\a\a.php. how do I go about it?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want wordpress to receive POST request parameters from /wordpress/a/a.php, backend add to cart and redirect to Checkout page

```
<?php
require( '../wp-load.php' );


//判断接收到的数据是否有指定参数 prod_id ,prod_qty,prod_name ，如果没有则不执行下面的代码
// if(!isset($_POST['prod_id']) || !isset($_POST['prod_qty']) || !isset($_POST['prod_name'])){
    
//     return;
// }else {


// 初始化 WooCommerce
    include_once  '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';
    add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');

    function custome_add_to_cart() {
        
            $product_id = 3170;

            // Prevent the add_to_cart action from looping
            remove_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', __FUNCTION__);

            global $woocommerce;

$addkey = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, '2');

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $cartkey = $cart_item['key'];
}
            
            
        
    }
// }

redirect();


function redirect()
{
    $url = 'https://*.com/checkout';
    header("Location: $url");

    exit();
}
//   echo "<script>var name = prompt('2');</script>";
?>
```

He doesn't use HOOK, he stops at HOOK. Without executing the function that follows, I don't know what's wrong with it
I tried the following code with fixed parameters, but it still didn't solve the problem！
Tried it many times.

Comment: Enable proper PHP error reporting, and check what that has to say. Most likely, I'm guessing, would be that you are trying to call some unknown function.